# selecting all next <tr> having padding left value is greater than the current tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi have a table which is dynamically created i can move the selected tr left value on click a button .i want to hide the tr having left value is greater than the selected tr when i click a button iuse some code but its not working

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  var parented = $(".selected").data("id");
  var currentid = parented + 1;
  while (true) {
    var chiledtrleft = $("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left");
    var parentleft = $("tr[data-id='" + parented + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left");
    if (chiledtrleft <= parentleft) {
      break;
    }

    $("tr[data-id='" + parented + "']> td:first-child").allnext("tr").hide();


  }
});
```

Comment: Share a complete example.. Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rayon i got it but i want the data id of a tr (a tr have a button ,when i click that button i want that tr data-id) i use this code but this is not good can you please help me "var parentid = $(this).tr.attr("data-id");"